# Find equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

[image]

My work:

I am shorting terminal a to c then finding the equivalent resitance between terminal b to d so now a=c
so 9 will parallel to 5 from b to a so equivalent 3.21
similarly from a to d it its 3.21 and both will be in series so total  I got \$\boxed{6.43\Omega}\$

But answer given Opion (A).Is there any mistake?

Comment: "to **the** load" (what load?), don't you need to know the resistance of "**the**" load in order to know what R should be? (For maximum power transfer the load should make up half of the resistance from the source to the ground. So a battery with 1 ohm internal resistance will have maximum power transfer with a 1 ohm load)

Comment: @HarrySvensson I am not gettting what are you telling..but according to you what should be the answer sir?

Comment: I think R is the load and we are supposed to assume the source impedance of the supply is zero.

Comment: @Rohit You have the right answer. Whomever graded it otherwise is wrong. Those are just two voltage dividers with the load connected between their midpoints. The Thevenin resistance is \$2\cdot\left(5\:\Omega\:\mid\mid\:9\:\Omega\right)\approx 6.42857\:\Omega\$. The maximum power in the variable resistor will occur when the variable resistor's value equals that Thevenin source resistance.